# How we can make a mask animation smoothly with Gsap

Tags: javascript, html, gsap

I have made an section where a full video will show and when we scroll down the a overlay div will show and video will look in a arch shape
I have used the Gsap and ScrollTrigger
I have create this using this refrace website https://simpl-archway.framer.website/

but I have made this reverse as per my need , but my version is not smooth it's not working poperly

here is the codepen link :

```
Link https://codepen.io/tarunRazor/pen/RweQoZe
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.